# How do you feed a csv with no headers into a python function - the function is returning 0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to get data from a common api in my industry and append all the data to a csv. The below code works until I try to give it a feed csv, which only contains a list of keywords starting at row 1 (no headers).

```
   parameters = {"type":"phrase_organic",
                "phrase":"",
                "key": API_KEY, 
                "database":"us",
                "export_column": "Dn,Ur,Fk",
                "display_limit":"10"}



keywords = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\stff\bulk_kw.csv", header=None)

res_df = None

for i in keywords:
    parameters["phrase"] = i  **#i is 0 for some reason**
    response = requests.get("https://api.semrush.com/", params=parameters)
    print(response.url)
    tmp_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.text), sep=";") 
    if res_df is None:
        res_df = tmp_df
    else:
        res_df = pd.concat([res_df, tmp_df])

res_df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\stff\SEMrush_call.csv")
```

I've tried a lot of things e.g.

- iteritems
- iterrows
- df.to_list()
- keywords.index
- unpacking the loop e.g. for i, j in keywords:

None give me what I want, which is a simple list of the values in the csv to loop through. What it's currently giving me is that i is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following change in my for loop and it works:

```
for i in keywords.values:
parameters["phrase"] = i  #i is 0 for some reason
response = requests.get("https://api.semrush.com/", params=parameters)
print(response.url)
tmp_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.text), sep=";") 
if res_df is None:
    res_df = tmp_df
else:
    res_df = pd.concat([res_df, tmp_df])
```

I understand that is because read_csv infers a header, in this case 0.  By adding keywords.values the program only looks at the values in the DataFrame.